# I want to Remove Android OS from my Computer(D-Drive)

Tags: windows-8.1, android, uninstall

I Installed Android in D-Drive of my Computer:

[image: As shown in this Image]

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit. Now I feel it is taking up more space and I rarely use it. I want to Remove it but I don't get answers on Google.

I see only these icons:
[image: I see only these icons]

I don't see any Uninstall Option anywhere. It is not installed in C-Drive along with Windows OS. But I get the option choose while booting the laptop. Whether to Boot with Windows or Android.
Please tell me ways to remove it completely from my laptop.

Comment: OS don't have deinstaller. Just open disk management MMC and delete the partitions that belong to Android. Be aware that if you delete the wrong partition you can loose important data.